# Из числа 1592 получить 31592 при помощи рекурсии

Tags: c++

Задача: Рекурсивно описать функцию Head3(N), которая вычисляет число, получаемое приписыванием слева цифры 3 к десятичной записи целого положительного числа N. Пример: Head3(1592)=31592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long Head3(unsigned long long N) {
    if (N >= 10) {
        return 10 * Head3(N / 10) + N % 10;
    } else {
        return 30 + N;
    }
}

int main () {
    printf("%llu", Head3(1592));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое